# Oracle DB Server with Multiple Databases - SGA and PGA size

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle DB server where there are 3 Databases, therefore each one was created with its own SGA and PGA sizes (SGA was approx. 20 GB and PGA is 30-40% of SGA) Total memory on the server is 64 GB.

Now I am checking the server memory consumption and it at 97%. Obviously because each one takes approx. 20 GB of RAM. Now I have to create a new Database and there is not enough RAM.

My question is more philosophical than technical, how should I restructure the SGA/PGA targets? what are the points I should keep in mind about each database when setting their SGA/PGA?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Do you definitely need new databases, or can you create a new schema in an existing one instead? Or can you go down the PDB route?

Comment: Using 19.3 Standard Edition 2. Schemas might not be a right solution as there is a question of security and we have a mix of Transactional and DW databases. I thought of the PDB route but its limited to 3 PDBs and our need is far greater than that.